# openGL and vector

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, stl

I am using openGL and am currently passing it a vertex array. 
It is run successfully when I pass OpenGL a vertex array with an array like

```
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.500000000f, 0.500000000f, 0.500000000f, 1.00000000f, 0.000000000f, 0.000000000f,
    0.500000000f, -0.500000000f, 0.500000000f, 1.00000000f, 0.000000000f, 0.000000000f,
    0.500000000f, 0.500000000f, -0.500000000f, 1.00000000f, 0.000000000f, 0.000000000f};
```

The problem is that when I passing it with a vector instead of the array like

```
    std::vector<GLfloat> vertices = {
    0.500000000f, 0.500000000f, 0.500000000f, 1.00000000f, 0.000000000f, 0.000000000f,
    0.500000000f, -0.500000000f, 0.500000000f, 1.00000000f, 0.000000000f, 0.000000000f,
    0.500000000f, 0.500000000f, -0.500000000f, 1.00000000f, 0.000000000f, 0.000000000f};
```

then I can't see the triangle in my window.

My code is almost like this
    https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/coordinate_systems_with_depth

And I changed this line

```
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

into

```
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And I changed these lines

```
    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // TexCoord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

into

```
    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // NormalVector attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
```

because I need the normal vector information to do something else.

Does anyone know how to use std::vector correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a `vector`, you need to use `vertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat)` instead of `sizeof(vertices)`. The `sizeof` operator will give you the number of bytes of memory the `vector` occupies on the stack, not the size of the dynamically allocated array it contains.